# Short story of airplane passengers removed before a crash, by humans from the future who are in need of healthy people. Not Millennium.

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, time-travel

I read a story where an agent from the future has a job of removing people from deadly crashes just before the event, and transporting them to the future. I have seen a few versions by searching the net, but not the one I read. This was in an anthology, it was written in the first person by the agent, and he barely made it off the plane before it crashed. The passengers arrived in the future, scared and confused. It is not the work upon which the film MILLENNIUM was based.

Comment: Not sure; except for the fact that you said it's NOT what Millenium was based upon, it fits with 'Air Raid' by John Varley.  If you want to read to verify it's not the right story, Baen has it available for free online [here](http://www.baenebooks.com/chapters/9781625791542/9781625791542___3.htm)  Millennium was based on the [book of the same name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millennium_%28novel%29) which was based on Varley's earlier story, Air Raid.

Comment: If it helps, Air Raid was the opening story in  ['Time Travelers (from Isaac Asimov's SciFi Magazine)'](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1346280.Time_Travelers_From_Isaac_Asimov_s_Science_Fiction_Magazine), since you mentioned it being in an anthology.

Answer (score 20):

Per KHW's comment, I think the story you're after is "**[Air Raid](http://www.sf-encyclopedia.com/entry/varley_john)**" by John Varley, originally posted in Asimov's Science Fiction - Spring 1977

- **First person story** - Check
- **Agent has job of removing people from planes before the crash** - Check
- **Agent only just survives** - Check
- **Passengers arrive in the future scared and confused** - Check

There's a full version to read [here](http://www.baenebooks.com/chapters/9781625791542/9781625791542___3.htm)

Answer (score 5):

The short story is "Air Raid" by John Varley.  The movie *Millennium* shares ideas with the short story but is substantially different.